# Debugging a linked list add(int index, T data) method

Tags: java, debugging

My problem is that the expected value is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but somehow I'm not getting that picked up in my conditionals at the start of my method.

This is the test case I'm not passing:

```
@Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testDSListAddInsertInvalidIndexHigh2() {
        DSListInterface<String> list = createStringList(3);
        list.add(3, "Hello");
    }
```

This is the conditional that should be catching it:

```
if(index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(); // invalid index, must be greater than zero 
if(isEmpty()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
if(index > size() + 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

Here's the complete code, all the other test cases worked but "one" (at index 1) isn't. I gave chatgpt a shoot at debugging and it helped a bit but I'm stuck.

```
public class DSList<T> implements DSListInterface<T> {
    private DSNode<T> first;
    
    public DSList() {
        super();
        this.first = null;
    }

    public void add(int index, T data) {
        if(index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(); // invalid index, must be greater than zero
        if(isEmpty()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        if(index > size() + 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
         
        DSNode<T> newNode = new DSNode<>();
        newNode.setData(data);
        
        if(index == 0) {
            newNode.setNext(first);
            first = newNode;
        }
        else {
                DSNode<T> beforeNode = null;
                DSNode<T> afterNode = first;
                
                 // empty list
        
                for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    if(afterNode == null) {
                        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(); // invalid index, too big
                    }
                    else {
                        if(i < index -1) {
                            beforeNode = afterNode.getNext();
                        }
                        afterNode = afterNode.getNext();
                    }
                }
                beforeNode.setNext(newNode);
                newNode.setNext(afterNode);
        }      
    }
```

Also here's the node class:

```
public class DSNode<T> {
    private T data;
    private DSNode<T> next;
    
    public DSNode() {
        super();
        this.data = null;
        this.next = null;
    }
    
    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
    
    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    public DSNode<T> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }
    
    public void setNext(DSNode<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```